# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, python, sql, pycharm

En MySQL tengo este error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 2

Mi código es:

```
    def show_transactions(self):


    query = """SELECT id_cliente, name_T, cantidad_T, destino, fecha_t FROM Transacciones JOIN
                usuarios ON usuarios.id_cliente = Transacciones.id_Clientes WHERE id_cliente = %s"""
    values = (show_id(self))
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    validation = cursor.fetchone()

    if validation:
        database.commit()
        print(validation)
```

Comment: TENGO UN ERROR CON LA RELACIÓN DE TABLAS, SOY ALGO NUEVO EN ESTO DE LAS BASES DE DATOS

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta usando el enlace Editar que esta justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas. Así puedes añadir toda la información sobre qué problema tienes. PD. Procura evitar el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas, que suele asumirse como que estás gritando (y por lo que leo no es la idea) :)

Comment: Revisa los [ejemplos de MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html). ¿Por qué `query` empieza y termina con `"""` ¿? Eso sería erróneo desde el punto de vista sintáctico. Debería ser así: `query = ("SELECT id_cliente, name_T, cantidad_T, destino, fecha_t FROM Transacciones JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_cliente = Transacciones.id_Clientes WHERE id_cliente = %s")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

¡Hola! Sinceramente tengo poca idea sobre bases de datos y python, pero buscando un poco por la red llegue a este pregunta de SO en ingles que podrían ayudarte.

He intentado por horas editar mi respuesta por la edicion traducida sin exito alguno. Me señalo un error pero no me dice exactamente donde esta mi error.

Te explico un poco:
El primer enlace que coloco hace referencia a una persona con tu mismo problema, viendo bien ahora la solucion que dan es para Python 2, pero no se cual sea tu version.
[En este enlace tiene el mismo problema que tu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665819/mysql-connector-errors-programmingerror-1064-4200-you-have-an-error-in-your#:%7E:text=errors.-,ProgrammingError%3A%201064%20(4200)%3A%20You%20have%20an%20error%20in%20your,as%20a%20%22skate%20board%22.)

Esta respuesta de acá me gusto muchísimo mas porque encara no solo el problema que tienes si no como enfrentar cualquier problema que surja en el futuro.. Explica que el problema que tienes esta en la sintaxis (o sea, *reglas de gramática*) por lo que la computadora no entiende lo que le estas diciendo.
Además de esto el propio MySql te esta diciendo como solucionar el problema refiriéndote al manual de uso del parámetro que estas usando mal (s% en este caso).
[Aquí hay una excelentísima respuesta sobre el error y como solucionarlo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

A todo esto supongo que te preguntas: ¿Qué puedo hacer entonces?

Como dije al principio, yo no se nada de base de datos y por ende tampoco del problema que tienes, lo siento, solo encontré esta información referente a tu problema que te podría ayudar si la echas una leída.

Disculpa por no haber podido editar la respuesta con la información traducida.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Buenas, mi capacidad de traducción es limitada. Intente hacerlo pero había términos que no comprendía del todo y llegue a la conclusión que terminaría confundiendo mas que ayudar así que opte por referirlo directamente. Iba a colocar esta justificación pero no lo vi necesario, una disculpa.

Comment: Oh, entiendo. Es que si es de baja calidad:( Igual intentare traducir y editar posteriormente con una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Ya he intentado editarla pero el editor me lanza un error de de identacion para código y la verdad que no tengo ni idea como solucionarlo. Ya me volví loco. No se donde esta el error:(